# Node.js: stable way to check for file changes?

Tags: javascript, file, node.js, directory, watch

Is there a stable way to check for file changes in node.js? I have tried the default `fs.watch`, but it is pretty buggy.

```
fs.watch(__dirname, function(event, filename){
    console.log(event + ' file ' + filename);
})
```

This logs a single change 3 times. And everyone is reporting a lots of bugs under different OS's.

*node v0.8.21, Ubuntu 12.10*

Comment: No experience with it personally, but try [node-inotify](https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fs.watch` is buggy, I'd just occasionally check the last modification stamp of a file to see if there are any updates using `fs.stat`